# Unable to set camera to view

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Unable to set camera to view

I'm not sure if related to updating blender to 2.92, though I'm suddendly unable to set the camera to the view anymore:

I store the view:
[image: txt]

Creating a new camera based on the view creates this:
[image: txt]

Tried Alt+Ctrl+0(Num) as well only to get the same useless view
[image]

Comment: if your camera has not the same focal as your 3D view, you won't get the exact same thing, maybe it's your problem here?

Comment: Thought the same... it even looks like the top view is orthographic instead of perspective.

Comment: or provide your blend file, so we can check it out

Comment: @moonboots Focal length is 50 on both. Attached file

Comment: there's no camera in your scene but if I create one it works fine, as Gordon says, make sure that you are in Perspective view when you navigate in your 3D view

Comment: Is there any chance to get the exact top view stored as camera? It is indeed orthographic